# type miss match error when filtering an array in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a simple user form in my macro-enabled Excel file, and there is a combo box (drop-down) in the form. I would like to populate the combo box options with specific header values (which are in the first row) in my Excel sheet. In my case, I have more than one hundred columns, and I just need a few of them that contain the "price" value.
Below is my VBA code when the user form is initializing:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim header_arr() As Variant
    Dim filtered_arr() As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    header_arr = ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight)).Value2

    filtered_arr = Filter(header_arr, "price") 'I am getting an error here.

    For Each item In filtered_arr 
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem (item)
    Next
    
End Sub
```

note for the code:

**header_arr** is the array of the first row in my sheet.

**filtered_arr** is the array of the first row in my sheet that contains the "price" value.

but when I run the code, I get run-time error 13 (type missmatch).
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The [VBA Filter function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filter-function) takes a 1D array as the first parameter while you are passing it a 2D array.  Also, the 4th argument `Compare` should probably be set to `vbTextCompare` to enable case-insensitivity (`Price = PRICE = price`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Populate a Combo Box With a Row

```vb
Sub PopulateCombobox()

    Const MatchString As String = "price"
     
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet ' improve!

    Dim hData():
    hData = ws.Range("A1", ws.Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Value ' or .Value2
    
    Dim sc As Long, dc As Long, HeaderString As String
    
    For sc = 1 To UBound(hData, 2)
        HeaderString = CStr(hData(1, sc))
        If InStr(1, HeaderString, MatchString, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            dc = dc + 1
            hData(1, dc) = hData(1, sc)
        End If
    Next sc
    
    If dc = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No headers containing """ & MatchString & """ found.", _
            vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If dc < sc - 1 Then
        ReDim Preserve hData(1 To 1, 1 To dc)
    'Else ' all columns contain the match string; do nothing
    End If
    
    With Me.ComboBox1
        ' Populate column:
        .List = Application.Transpose(hData)
        ' or populate row (probably a bad idea):
        '.ColumnCount = dc
        '.List = hData
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

As @VBasic2008 has pointed out, Filter() requires a one-dimensional array.  Therefore, you can convert header_arr into a one-dimensional array by transposing it twice.  Then, once you've filtered the array, you can simply use the List property of the combobox to assign the filtered array.

Note the following...

1. filtered_arr has been declared as a dynamic String array, although it could have been declared as Variant.
2. The target worksheet has been specified, change the name accordingly.

Here's the code...

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim header_arr() As Variant
    Dim filtered_arr() As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change the sheet name accordingly

    header_arr = ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight)).Value2
    
    With Application
        header_arr = .Transpose(.Transpose(header_arr))
    End With

    filtered_arr = Filter(header_arr, "price", True, vbTextCompare)
    
    Me.ComboBox1.List = filtered_arr

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much @Domenic. I think while both answers are functional, your solution is much easier to understand, at least for me!